# SSL handshake failure using client certificate and Retrofit

Tags: android, apache, retrofit, okhttp, tls1.2

I have a client-server application (Android client, Apache Http server) communicating through mutual authentication (TLS 1.2). The problem: Sometimes the connection (login) fails with an SSL error.

**This works:**

1. Enrol client certificate
2. Login

**This does *not* work:**

1. Enrol client certificate
2. Login
3. Delete client certificate
4. Enrol ("same") client certificate
5. Login

Note: Killing the app after step 4 and then start it and perform step 5 works.

Possible explanations that I can think of:

1. **Some old resources being reused** (like the old client certificate).
   It looks like everything relevant (OkHttpClient etc) is re-instantiated as expected.
2. **SSL renegotiation** Perhaps this is broken when using a new credential? Is there a way to disable it?

**Android (client) logs:**

```
02-11 15:58:29.827  21352-23374/com.mycompany E/com.mycompany.Connection﹕ ERROR Read error: ssl=0x99116c00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:1409441B:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert decrypt error (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1303 0x9928fa60:0x00000003)
    error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1036 0xa613bcc5:0x00000000)
    retrofit.RetrofitError: Read error: ssl=0x99116c00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:1409441B:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert decrypt error (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1303 0x9928fa60:0x00000003)
    error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1036 0xa613bcc5:0x00000000)
```

**Server logs:**

```
[Thu Feb 11 14:58:16.736172 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] [client 194.161.218.157:36836] AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed
[Thu Feb 11 14:58:16.736172 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] SSL Library Error: error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01
[Thu Feb 11 14:58:16.736172 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] SSL Library Error: error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed
[Thu Feb 11 14:58:16.736172 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] SSL Library Error: error:1408807B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_cert_verify:bad signature
[Thu Feb 11 14:59:24.655282 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] [client 194.161.218.157:34530] AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed
[Thu Feb 11 14:59:24.655282 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] SSL Library Error: error:04067084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data too large for modulus
[Thu Feb 11 14:59:24.655282 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 4424:tid 2088] SSL Library Error: error:1408807B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_cert_verify:bad signature
```

My setup:
**Android version** 5.1.1
**Retrofit version** 1.9.0
**OkHttp version** 2.7.2
**Apache HTTP server version** 2.4.17

Any clues what could be wrong or suggestions what to do to get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the issue by not setting the ConnectionPool explicitly on the rest adapter (thus the same, default, instance is re-used).